# Размер блока относительно изображения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется блок в него используя `append()` вставляется абсолютно позиционированное изображение и поверх еще svg. Но раз это все абсолютное соответственно высоты у родительского блока нет, как следствие ничего не видно. Решил что можно вычислить высоту элемента-изображения тоесть в моем случае `img` и выставить эту высоту родительскому, но загвоздка заключается в том, что на момет вычисления высоты `img` он пустой и высота получается `0px`. Каким способом можно решить эту проблему? Можно ли узнать размер изображения до загрузки или решить как то по другому эту задачу?

p.s. Изображение растянуто на всю ширину экрана.

```
<div class="container-fluid interactive">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-svg">
            <!-- еще код некоторый -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function renderBuilding(elementId, feed) {
    let svgFloors = '';
    buildingId = +elementId;
    // далее я просто собираю строку из элементов которые будут отображены в svg на странице
    $.each(feed[buildingId].entrance, function(indexEntrance, e) {
        $.each(e.floors, function(indexFloor, f) {
            svgFloors += f.svgFloor;
        });
    });
    $('.container-svg').append(`<div id="building-${buildingId}" class="container-svg-wrap building">
        <img src="${feed[buildingId].imgBuilding}">
        <svg version="1.1" data-id="${buildingId}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 3200 1564" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2500 700;" xml:space="preserve">
            ${svgFloors}
        </svg>
    </div>`);

    let heightImage = 0;
    let checkHeightImage = setInterval(function() {
        heightImage = $('.container-svg .building img').height();
            if(heightImage > 0) {
                $('.interactive>.container, .building').css('height', heightImage);
                clearInterval(checkHeightImage);
            }
    }, 10);
}
</script>
```

Необходимо задать высоту вот таким селекторам `.interactive>.container, .building`. Пока что не придумал ничего лучше чем задачть через `setInterval`, но как мне кажется это прям какое-то костыльное решение.

p.s.s. все это изображение дома с наложенным поверх него svg этажей, поэтому все абсолютно (уровень знаний пока что не позволяет сделать это как то по другому)

Comment: а почему нужно чтобы изображение было спозиционировано абсолютно?

Comment: задай тегу `img{padding:100%;}`

Comment: не поможет. у родителя нулевая высота, т.к. img `position: absolute;`

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, лучше бы он код показал...  А `padding` всегда помогает, ну если не процентах, так `vw, vh, vmax, vmin` есть....

Comment: Абсолютно потому что там и изображение и svg поверх него. Проценты и относительные величины не получается использовать потому что во первых это надо подгадывать под определенное изображение. а оно может со временем поменяться и снова сидеть гадать (лично мое мнение)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
<div>
    <img onload="this.parentNode.style.cssText = 'width:'this.offsetWidth+'px;'+'height:'+this.offsetHeight+'px;'"></img>
</div>
```